# How many submissions a month per Cognito free tier account?

Tags: cognito-forms

How many submissions a month are we able to have with a free Cognito account? What is the storage limit and what is actually stored? Is that the amount of forms and data collected? Or would that only be uploads?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms. Currently, we have unlimited forms, unlimited fields, unlimited entries and unlimited storage. We store all of your submission data, including any uploads.

However, at some point next year we will roll out some tiered data and entry plans, which you can find out more about in our [blog post](http://blog.cognitoapps.com/2013/12/17/whats-cognito-forms-our-online-forms-engine-going-to-cost/).

We wanted to make our pricing very simple and representative of how much people actually use their forms. With tiered plans, free users will be limited to 100 MB of data and 500 entries per month. The first paid tier (at just $5 per month) will give them 1 GB of data and 5,000 entries per month – ten times more than the free plan.

All plans, however, will always have unlimited forms and unlimited fields.